# Generating a matrix by applying function to all pairs

Tags: r

Let `F` be a function that takes two arguments and returns a numeric value, and let `X` and `Y` be vectors of values suitable as first and second arguments (respectively) of `F`.

Is there a "functional" (i.e. loop-free), and convenient, way to generate the *matrix* whose *ij*-th entry is the number

```
F(X[[i]], Y[[j]])
```

?

In Python, I would do this:

```
[[F(x, y) for y in Y] for x in X]
```

In Mathematica,

```
Table[F[x, y], {x, X}, {y, Y}]
```

Etc.

Is there something similarly straightforward in R?

---

UPDATE: regarding `outer`:

```
> F <- function (c1, c2) utf8ToInt(c1) - utf8ToInt(c2)
```

This `F` is just a silly example to illustrate my point.  It works when used by itself:

```
> F('A', 'a')
[1] -32
```

But:

```
> outer(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), F)
Error in outer(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),  : 
  dims [product 25] do not match the length of object [1]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In utf8ToInt(c1) : argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
2: In utf8ToInt(c2) : argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

I repeat, the above is just an artificial example, concocted only to illustrate my point.  (Therefore, getting it to work in a non-generalizable way is of no use to me.)

Comment: I think you want `?outer`

Comment: @d.b : I tried `outer`, and it's not even close.  Please see the update to my post.

Comment: Well, it's awfully close after reading `?outer`... `outer(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5], Vectorize(F))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either vectorize `F` so that you can use it with `outer` or do something like below

```
sapply(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), function(a)
           sapply(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), function(b)
                     F(a,b)))
#    A   B   C   D   E
#a -32 -31 -30 -29 -28
#b -33 -32 -31 -30 -29
#c -34 -33 -32 -31 -30
#d -35 -34 -33 -32 -31
#e -36 -35 -34 -33 -32
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the help for `outer`, F needs to be vectorised...

```
F <- Vectorize(function (c1, c2) utf8ToInt(c1) - utf8ToInt(c2))
outer(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), F)
```